# socket.io - encrytpting comunication between server and client

Tags: javascript, socket.io

**Hello everytone,**

I have created a simple **socket.io** server that sends messages to a web application, once the application receives anything, it responds back to the server with another message..

And I suppose that all the communication between them is unencrypted. Now the question is, what's the best way to make the communication encrypted?

Is there any module for this?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Just use `wss://` as protocol instead of `ws://` in the JavaScript. Then (if your server supports it) you connection will be secure.

Sadly i can't add any details, cause i dont know what server you are using..

Comment: could you please send me any link or post an example about how to establish secure connection between these two elements?

Comment: well the thing is that I don't use express framework in my project.

Comment: So you are only using WebSockets? Just socket.io and.. ?

Comment: well then you use http as the server? Instead of using http just use https.

Comment: well I have found couple of examples on other forums... but most of them are using express or other frameworks..So a working example  (without express) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Then it would be nice to see your complete server/socket.io code, or well the important parts of it.